# making the images secure so as to make it not accessed by others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-s3, paperclip

I use paperclip gem to store images to s3 and it is displayed with the url of amazon. What i need is, i want to store images in s3 and i want only the users to view the images by using the url. Now if the url is known the image can be accessed anywhere. So how can this be restricted?

Comment: what kind of authentication scheme does your app currently use?

Comment: I just tried the PaperClipExample and i use s3 to store but i could access the images when open in new window with the amazon url. How can i restrict because it makes anybody use the url

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed description of how to do this on the paperclip wiki on Github:
[check here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Restricting-Access-to-Objects-Stored-on-Amazon-S3). Just provide the links created in that way only to users with permission and it should work fine.